# why do ref parameters in functions for stable_sort need const

Tags: c++, sorting

If I remove the `const` from the function parameters clang throws an error. This error in combination with missing `const` only appear with ref variables. What's going on?

```
vector<string> v = {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox"};

bool compareWords(const string & s1, const string & s2)
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}

stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compareWords);
```

Comment: my best guess would be: since its sorting, it wouldnt want the data modified mid sort and potentially have an invalid sort. since it passes addresses to compareWords, those could be modified, so it reqiuires const to fix this

Comment: here: `error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'basic_string<[3 * ...]>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'basic_string<[3 * ...]>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking,

```
bool compareWords(string & s1, string & s2)
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}
```

should work. The only requirement for `compareWords` is that it should not modify the arguments.

Here's some info from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

> The signature does not need to have `const &`, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.

However, some compilers take that requirement to mean that the arguments should be either `const &` or simply objects.

Comment: I think strictly speaking it *might* work without `const`. The standard says "It is assumed that `comp` will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator," which is a little strangely worded, but I think it's implying that the comparison function is assumed to not modify its parameters. Therefore, it is valid for a compiler to require them to be `const`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: Oh, it sounds like you're saying that non-`const` should compile fine, but some compilers do it wrong.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, the standard does not say anything about whether the argument type should be `const&` or not. It only says that function should not modify the objects. When a compiler insists that the argument type be `const&`, it's being more careful, more strict than what the standard requires.

Comment: "Being more strict than what the standard requires" is another way of saying it is rejecting a well-formed program.

Comment: I think we are agreeing, but my problem is with your wording that "Strictly speaking, [the code] should work." Actually, strictly speaking the code may or may not work, depending on some unspecified behaviour, which is whether or not the compiler is imposing this extra requirement. The compiler is free to be stricter in this case, because the standard allows it to be.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: Where does the standard allow the compiler (or rather library, in this case) to be stricter?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley In the quote I gave above: "It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator." If that is assumed, the library is free to assume that the arguments must be `const`.

Comment: Hm... if "apply any non-constant function" includes binding to a non-const reference then OP's example is undefined behaviour. Otherwise, it is well formed and well defined.

Answer (score 1):

It's to help you ensure that you don't modify the arguments to the comparator.

If you were to modify the elements being sorted during the sort operation then the comparator might return inconsistent results, which would break the sorting algorithm - with potentially unlimited ill effects ("undefined behavior").

Answer (score 1):

By saying `string & s1` as a parameter without the `const` implies that you will be changing the underlying value back in the calling function.  However, that value is the return value of a function -- it's not stored anywhere, it can't be changed.

(OK, due to some compiler magic it is stored somewhere, but that location is not accessible to the calling function, so you are still implying you want to do something that you can't do)

Comment: what's strange is that I can do: `bool compareWords(string & s1, string & s2)` with normal `sort`

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard

> It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function
>   through the dereferenced iterator.

So to provide this restriction objects of dereferenced iterators are considered as const references.